# react-native-maps - AIRGoogleMapManager.pointForCoordinate was called with 2 arguments but expects 3 arguments

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-maps

Setup react-native-maps as described in installation instructions. Everything working as expected except the MapView.pointForCoordinate() method.

Anytime I use the method I get the following error:

> AIRGoogleMapManager.pointForCoordinate was called with 2 arguments but expects 3 arguments. If you haven't changed this method yourself, this usually means that your versions of the native code and JavaScript code are out of sync. Updating both should make this error go away.

Versions used:
"react-native": "0.54.4",
"react-native-maps": "0.21.0"

Testing on iOS Simulator.

I have tried to rebuilding project from scratch.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a bug inside `react-native-maps` [sources](https://github.com/react-community/react-native-maps/blob/master/lib/components/MapView.js#L681) (link to the line with issue). Should be this at that line:

```
this._runCommand('coordinateForPoint', [point, (err, res) => {
      if (err) {
        reject(err)
      } else {
        resolve(res)
      }
    }])
```

So, I recommend you:

1. Fork this library
2. Fix that line
3. Commit and push changes to your repository at github
4. Run `npm i github:{YOUR_GITHUB_USERNAME}/react-native-maps`
5. Run `react-native start --reset-cache` to be sure that it won't run cached files
6. Give another try for `pointForCoordinate`

---

By the way, the `coordinateForPoint` [method](https://github.com/react-community/react-native-maps/blob/master/lib/components/MapView.js#L699) has the same issue, and the fix steps are the same.

Note: **Changes are the same** as for `pointForCoordinate` method, **but another one line**.